# Как проверять telegram каналы на наличие комментариев?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, pyrogram

Необходимо модулем pyrogram проверять тг канал на наличие комментариев, вроде как метод [GetGroupsForDiscussion](https://docs.pyrogram.org/telegram/functions/channels/get-groups-for-discussion#pyrogram.raw.functions.channels.GetGroupsForDiscussion) должен это делать, но он не хочет принимать аргументы. А колхозить, проверяя на ошибку при получении количества комментариев не хочется.